# Can anyone id this flower

Tags: species-identification, flowers

I took this photo on Madeira, in a botanical garden.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [*Kleinia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleinia), a genus from Asteraceae family. It is a succulent  native to  Africa.

I found a number of possible candidates, there may be more:

1. [Kleinia abyssinica](https://translate.google.co.in/translate?hl=en&sl=fr&u=https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleinia_abyssinica&prev=search)

   [image]
2. [Kleinia fulgens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleinia_fulgens)
3. [Kleinia stapeliiformis](https://toptropicals.com/cgi-bin/garden_catalog/cat.cgi?find=Kleinia)
4. [Kleinia pendula](https://toptropicals.com/cgi-bin/garden_catalog/cat.cgi?find=Kleinia)

P.S. There's not much free information from authoritative sources online about this genus. There are similarities in the blossoms' colour across  the Genus and also differences within a single species so to do a species level ID more information about the plant is needed.